# Dynamic constraint on Xamarin.IOS to fill the entire screen

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, storyboard

I need to make dynamically, without references to other constraints, constraints to make a dynamically generated view fill the entire screen.

Width is not a problem, height is.

I tried this:

```
 NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat("V:|-0-[viewLoader]-0-|", 0, new NSDictionary(), viewsDictionary)
```

but in iPhones with notch it doesn't work since parent doesn't occupy the notch and bottom navigation gesture area.

Also tried this:

```
this.lastView.AddConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat("V:[viewLoader(==" + UIScreen.MainScreen.ApplicationFrame.Height + ")]", 0, new NSDictionary(), viewsDictionary));
```

but the height doesn't count the extra space of the notch and the bottom navigation gesture bar.

How can I do this? I need to fill the entire screen of any device.

Comment: Did you set the safe area? You can provide the full code and effect on your device .

Comment: Thanks for the interest but I have solved it. The problem was the storyboard that was being loaded as a view had in itself its constraints set to its safe area, so I was really confused about it.

Comment: You can post the answer and accept it , which will help more people :)